# accessing SQL syntax reference in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Finding it a little bit tedious migrating to the new Mysql Workbench (5.2.22) even though it has many more features than the older GUI tools.  Right now I'm confused why I can't find an SQL reference when I open the Doc Library.  Is there a way to access this info within the workbench, I'd prefer not to have to open a browser to access reference info on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to be able to access reference material without being connected to the internet you can download the MySQL Manual for offline viewing. It is available in a variety of formats such as HTML, PDF, CHM, Man pages and a couple more. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Comment: Probably just wishful thinking that they included the reference within the workbench like they made available in the earlier version of the GUI tools.

Comment: I didn't know it was an issue until you brought it up. I always just use the online docs powered by Google searches. At the very least it should be a component in the installer to allow the user to decide if they want it installed or not. I guess you could always email Oracle and suggest it.